# HTML Mutli Select Not Posting Values Back to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a select box in a html form that does not post values back to php.

```
<select multiple='multiple' name='mydropdown'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

in PHP if I have a look at the `$_REQUEST` it returns a single value for the LAST selected value in the select box.

What do I need to change or edit in order to get a array or list of selected items posted back so that I can handle the result in PHP?

I would like to transform the select into a `JQuery multi` select box so if your answer could apply to JQuery select boxes aswell I would appreciate it

Comment: Do you have this dropdown repeating multiple times on your page? If so, change name to `name='mydropdown[]'`, it's _usually_ called HTML input array and preserves values of all dropdowns with same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP requires that form control names end in `[]` if you are getting multiple values from the same name.

```
<select multiple='multiple' name='mydropdown[]'>
```

It doesn't matter if the reason for getting multiple values is multiple form controls with the same name, or a single select `multiple` element.